# Right Clicking Properties and Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int appears

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I know there are posts and answers to the above error, however my error comes up when I am right clicking and selecting properties on my database, rather than executing a script/query, which is what the rest of the posters have put on here.

[image]

In actual fact there are no tables in my database (after deleting them) and the message still appears.

[image]

Before i deleted my tables i did convert any int to big int

```
SELECT
CAST(Math AS BIGINT) AS Math1
FROM MyTable
```

and thought that might do the trick but it hasn't, neither has deleting the table(s) from the database.

Does anyone have a clue as to what it might be?

Comment: Odd... I would drop and recreate the database. Since you deleted all tables, that shouldn't be an issue

Comment: Is you SSMS version same or greater that server version? While accessing SQL server 2016 with SSMS 2014 for example various mystical errors pop up.

Comment: I think that might be the only option to drop and recreate...it might well be that there are mystical errors that pop up. My fear is that if I had tables in the database that aren't easily dropped and recreated etc, then the issue will still remain, if it ever pops up again..

Answer (score 0):

> however my error comes up when I am right clicking and selecting
>   properties on my database, rather than executing a script/query, which
>   is what the rest of the posters have put on here.

When you ask SSMS for database properties it does execute some code, even if you don't see it.
To find out what exact code is causing this error, use `SQL Server Profiler`.

Here you'll find what events you should pick and how to narrow down the statement that caused the error: 
[How to trace SQL Server database errors and exceptions with SQL Profiler](https://nimblegecko.com/how-to-trace-sql-server-database-errors-and-exceptions-with-sql-profiler/)